# Neo4j using params[:search] in controller and like in the model

Tags: search, neo4j, neo4j.rb

The line in controller in the index method is:

```
@authors = Author.as(:a).search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => @page, :per_page => @per_page, return: :a, order: :name)
```

Looking to retrieve all authors having a substring part of the name.

The search method in the author model is:

```
  private
    def self.search(search)
      where("name =~ '.*:search.*'", search: "%#{search}%")
    end
```

I am trying to use the same pattern I used with ActiveModel, but I am getting an error:

name not defined (line 1, column 39) "MATCH (result_author:`Author`) WHERE (name =~ '.*:search.*') AND (result_author.search = {result_author_search}) WITH result_author as result_author RETURN COUNT(result_author)

Don't know how to write this properly.

Comment: Please specify which driver you use and in which version.

Comment: neo4j (4.1.2, 4.1.1)
neo4j-core (4.0.2, 4.0.1, 4.0.0)
neo4j-will_paginate_redux (0.3.4)

Comment: I guess it is neo4j.rb then

Comment: Yes, I am developing an app using RoR and Neo4j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That form of `where` doesn't work (though we've been talking about implementing it).  You should do this instead:

```
def self.search(node_var, search)
  all.where("#{node_var}.name =~ {search}").params(search: ".*#{search}.*")
end


@authors = Author.as(:a).search(:a, params[:search]).paginate(:page => @page, :per_page => @per_page, return: :a, order: :name)
```

The `all` is also important in class methods which allow you to make a chain like this

Comment: I changed the self.search method as suggested above. The error now is: 

name not defined (line 1, column 28) "MATCH (a:`Author`) WHERE ( name =~ '.*'+ {search} +'.*' ) WITH a as a RETURN COUNT(a)"

pointing to the controller line show below:

if params[:search]
      @authors = Author.as(:a).search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => @page, :per_page => @per_page, return: :a, order: :name)

Comment: Even changing a little bit to this:

all.where(' name =~ ".*"+ {search} +".*" ', search: "%#{search}%")

and I am still getting the same error: name not defined ...

Comment: Ah, right, because you need to specify the node variable in the cypher.  I just edited with a possible fix, but I'm not entirely sure it will work.  Sharing with my colleage

Comment: I changed as suggested after editing and now the error is: undefined local variable or method `identity' for Author(name: String):Class in the search method, pointing to the edited line in the search method.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't really surprise me too much.  I just made an edit which should work.  It means you need to add another parameter for your `search` method.  I really want to solve this problem, generally though....

Comment: If I am going to create a git repo and give you access to the repo, this may help? I really don't know what to do next.

Comment: Sure, if you like.  Did the most recent edit not work?

Comment: No, the most recent edit did not work. Same error. I will create the repo and let you know when is done.

Comment: I created the repo (pubic) with the code including the "1 Answer" provided. Here is the link: https://github.com/levi-l-damian/woka The current error is: Type mismatch: expected Boolean, Collection<Boolean> or Collection<Collection<Boolean>> but was String (line 1, column 53) "MATCH (a:`Author`) WHERE (a.name =~ '.*'+ {search} +'.*') WITH a as a RETURN COUNT(a)" and pointing to the AuthorsController#index, the line after the if params[:search]

Comment: Ah, sorry.  The solution was easy enough once I tried it.  You can't concatenate strings with params in cypher queries.  Just edited with a better solution

Comment: Many thanks, the new edit worked perfectly. I will close the question.